# First-time US passport applicant from abroad

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

I applied for my first US passport at a US embassy 4 weeks ago. Has anyone ever had a similiar experience? How long will it take? According to the state website it’ll take 4 to 6 weeks. From an email exchange with the embassy, a week.

I’m getting anxious because I will have to go back to the US in 2 months. I’m worried about possible issues such as taxes (I never filed because I’ve been living abroad my whole life and completely unaware of this obligation). I don’t know my Social Security Number (which I have asked SSA to forward to the passport application), and they asked for progression photos because I’m an adult applying for the first time.

Also I can’t check my application status because I don’t know my SSN.

How long did it take for you?

Comment: You seem to have a pretty unique situation going for you, so how long it took anyone else isn't going to do anything but make you more anxious.

Comment: You said "go back to the US"; were you in the US before?

Comment: I was when I was born. Then left the country as a baby with my mother’s passport.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas that is an excellent point

Comment: It took about four weeks (after the appointment) to get a passport for a child born abroad, but that might not be representative of your situation.

Comment: @Louis which country did you apply from?

Comment: @user77916 Finland.

Comment: Why do you think you have s social security number? I would be unsurprised if you do not.

Comment: @phoog I was required to check with the Social Security Administration and turns out I have one but they will not dislcose it to me

Comment: FYI as a US citizen, in addition to being required to file income tax returns (which will be a hassle but with FEIE and FTC probably result in little or no tax actually owed), you were required to annually report if you had non-US bank/financial accounts and some other assets over various thresholds, which you probably did, in _two_ ways: once on your income tax return, and also in a separate process called FBAR (google it). There is no tax on such assets, but there are harsh penalties for failing to report them, so this could well be the bigger problem for you. ...

Comment: ... If 'go back' means you are moving back to the US permanently (or long-term) I encourage you once you are settled to find a good accountant or perhaps even an Enrolled Agent (see www.naea.org) to help with this, and look into whether the 'streamlined filing compliance' program works for you. You can also find several Qs on these topics already on money.SX, or ask new ones if you need to. Good luck.

Comment: @phoog For many years the US has assigned SSNs to most people [at birth](https://secure.ssa.gov/poms.nsf/lnx/0110205505).

Comment: @Louis how did they notify you? Did you get an orange slip for collection with date to collect? I did not get after that the appointment because I was missing a document which then I sent to them through email.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I’ve looked into that and based on my understanding in order to go through the streamlined filing compliance I need my SSN. In order to get my SSN from outside of the US I need a US passport. Seems like a Catch-22 situation if they refuse to issue my passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton and it would be unsurprising for an overseas first-time adult passport application to come from someone who has been born abroad. Conversely, I wonder what would happen with the newborn noncitizen child of a diplomat, at least in a hospital outside the Washington and New York areas. It would be perhaps the first confusion in a lifetime of confusion.

Comment: Hi, came back to report my experience. So I got my passport after 4 weeks. I applied on the 20th and got it on the 23rd the next month. It could’ve been longer because I applied for the card as well.